# ありがとう pitch and intonation

Tags: pitch-accent, intonation

NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典 seems to only list ありがとう{LHLLL}. And I think the polite form is most commonly ありがとうございます{LHLLLLHHHL}?

But I think I also hear what sounds to me like ありがとう{LHHHH} or ありがとう{LHLHH}. Is it an intonation issue?

Some examples:

- Am I correct in thinking [this one](https://youtu.be/oRCsy25ER64?t=231) is 語尾上げ? 「君、今日も頑張ってくれてありがとう」
- What about [this one](https://youtu.be/IBrUxfKQdEA?t=975)?
- And [this one](https://youtu.be/zwW9qvs2M50?t=859)
- [This](https://youtu.be/alM-g--UJt4?t=778)
- [This](https://youtu.be/W__7mkTAYiI?t=363)
- I'm not sure if [this one](https://youtu.be/YHzoGWjcLRg?t=530) is ありがとうございます{LHHHHHHHHL}

Answer (score 3):

I think all of your clips can be explained by:

1. Quoting と or とか can make the previous word 尾高 sometimes.
2. You have some non-標準語 clips. For instance, it's ありがと＼う in Kansai-ben. https://youtu.be/yqWcakJhaok?t=605
3. The last clip sounds like あり＼がとうございま＼す to me.

It's not a good idea to use TedX talks from different parts in Japan as a reference for standard pitch.

Answer (score 2):

The fourth and fifth are said with one of the natural intonations, not the annoying kind. The first three are also that, quoted with と or って.

At normal speed, the polite form would be ありがとうございます{LHLLLLLLLL}, but with the flat part not really staying flat but going further down. It's just that the last speaker’s accent is such that the initial fall is not very clear.

It's ありがとう{LLLHL} in Kansai-ben, by the way.

Comment: You mentioned there's an annoying kind of pronunciation of ありがとう. I wonder if these ones are what you referred to: [(1)](https://youtu.be/hbTA_jDPLGQ) [(2)](https://youtu.be/oWTWRITdjL4) [(3)](https://youtu.be/zcm-8MZlVN4) [(4)](https://youtu.be/wqiZAp3qtck). They seem to deviate from the standard pitch pattern. I wonder: 1. Is this an issue of pitch or intonation? Is the rise at the end that I'm hearing a change in pitch or just a rising intonation? 2. Is this 女性語? Something that only women say? 3. It doesn't occur in 敬語, does it?

Comment: @EddieKal - I denied those you asked about were said in the so-called 語尾上げ intonation, which usually refers to the kind that many people find annoying. It usually occurs where one part of a sentence connects to the next. If anyone can annoy you with ありがとう alone, that's probably for another reason, such as a sarcastic tone and a nasal voice. Anyway, none of the new set is that. They represent a close relationship. Women do tend to speak like that much more than men.

Comment: Okay thank you. Just to make sure I understand you correctly: those are not 語尾上げ? So is that an uncommon pitch pattern in 標準語 then? like ありがとう{LHLHH}?

Comment: @EddieKal - Not all rising intonations are 語尾上げ just like not all rising intonations are considered uptalk. And there's nothing wrong with the pitch.